# Guideline when designing a database in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-schema, database-backups, tablespace

I am designing a database in `Postgresql` and I would like to have some expert advices before refactorizing my work.

The database naturally contains different parts that I plan to separate into schemas in order to have a mangling of object names that reflect logical organization of them. About 20 tables are for scientific purposes and 20 others are technical and 20 furthers are about administrative tasks.
Is that a good idea or am I misleading myself into a management overhead that I will regret later?

The database contains 3 tables that are huge. By huge, I mean there is more than 60 millions of rows in it and they might grow a little bit. I think I will create special tablespace for that tables. I would like to do it, in order to separate logically the place where data are stored because the rest of the database should be backuped in a different way than that three tables.

Further more one those 3 tables contains binary data that are not heavy but weight a bit when multiplying by the amount of rows and also this table grows faster than the 2 others. Then I will periodically purge it after backuping the table.

Is it a good idea to have more than one tablespace in a database? If so, is there any precaution to be taken when proceeding this way?

Thank you in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing good names & grouping database stuffs is always a wise choice, and such overheads are not usually considerable.
About separating tablespace of a single database, it also should not cause any special problem, I've a similar database (but in mysql) that has a large file table and I had to move all of it's content to another server for some optimization reasons and i had no problem with it till now.
There is a very more important matter in RDBMS designing and that's CORRECT TABLE INDEXING. I think choosing good indexes is most critical phase of designing a relational database and you'll see it's effect soon (when you begin to write JOIN queries!).
In general, designing and implementing database is an experimental job that depends to your situation and expertness, so you can't seek for a solid instruction.